# Bibliometric data to rank research institutions

Tags: data-request, research, bibliometrics

I would like to rank research institutions on its impact in scientific fields like bioinformatics or molecular biology.

Are there repositories of bibliometric data (aggregated by research institution, and research field) that can be used to this purpose?

Comment: I think this a clearly stated request for Open Data, I see no reason to close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Plum Analytics http://plumanalytics.com/ i believe does research institution level data, though I don't think they have open data. though maybe you can ask about using it
- there's also altmetric.com and impactstory.org, but those likely won't help too much, though both have somewhat open or open APIs
- Crossref has an API http://det.crossref.org/ for some metrics across the articles they mint DOIs for - you'd have to combine metrics by institution yourself